# Image noise removal

Tags: image, noise

I am currently doing my thesis and it is about paper currency recognition.

My problem is I can't remove the vandals in the scanned images of the money. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: wait! If you're doing the thesis, shouldn't you be the expert?

Comment: This is a really hard problem.

Comment: Sorry Mitch Wheat but Im an undergrad. I honestly believe that Im not an expert. But thanks for the comment!

Comment: This looks like a pretty fundamental part of your thesis. Do you really expect this can be answered with a simple SO question? Research, my friend. And when you're done, post the answer here I bet it's really interesting :-)

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following image pre-processing techniques:

Image Resizing,
Binarization,
Marginal Noise Removal,
Skew Detection,
Adaptive Thresholding,
Image Smothening/Filter,
Erosion,
Dilation,

Search on this topics... This one is pretty tough. Goodluck.. :D